# Stop ng serve from parsing the entire app code base and only use the used files

Tags: angular, webpack

Ang 5 app built with the ang-cli with the start script as:

```
"start": "ng serve",
```

The problem is.. during development there are invariably files in the code base that are not in use and thus maybe import something that does not exist yet. running the above start script for some reason checks every single file in the code base and these non-used files break the build.

Is there a way to tell ng server to ignore non used files?

Answer (score 1):

If files are in angular root folder, you need to exclude them in tsconfig.json.

I.e
`"exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]`